# Problem with setting UIView's backgroundColor from a UIColor property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, uicolor

I'm trying to set a view's backgroundColor based on a property that I set in another class. The view class partly looks like this:

```
// Interface iVar and property
UIColor * coverColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor * coverColor;

// Where I set up the view
CGRect cover = CGRectMake(19.0, 7.0, coverWidth, coverHeight);
UIView * coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cover];
coverView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
coverView.backgroundColor = coverColor;
[self.contentView addSubview:coverView];
[coverView release];
coverView = nil;

// In my other class where I try to set the color
cell.coverColor = noteblock.color;

// noteblock is a instance of a custom model (NSManagedObject) class. It have a property called color. The type is set to Transformable. It looks like this:
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor * color;
@dynamic color;

// I set the color like this when I create new Noteblock objects:
newNoteblock.color = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:212.0/255.0 blue:81.0/255.0 alpha:1] autorelease];
```

When I run the app in the simulator, no color shows, it's transparent. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Where do you pass the color value to coverColor property here ? Are u really getting a value stored in tat ? chk using NSLog ...

Comment: When i run NSLog(@"%@", noteblock.color); (the color stored in the database) I get the following output: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.831373 0.317647 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `cell.coverColor = noteblock.color;` changes the property coverColor but not the backgroundColor of coverView.
You could set the background color directly (without additional property):

```
coverView = [cell coverView];
coverView.backgroundColor = noteblock.color;
```

or override the setter of coverColor:

```
-(void) setCoverColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    if (coverColor != color)
    {
        [coverColor release];
        coverColor = [color retain];
        coverView.backgroundColor = coverColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work, as the author wants to set the `-backgroundColor` of `coverView` and not the cell's one. You need to get a reference to `coverView` using either tags or another iVar.

Comment: Thins works, but I don't want to set the backgroundColor of the view but one of the view's subviews. Sorry, wasn't clear about that in the question. Like this: `CGRect cover = CGRectMake(19.0, 7.0, coverWidth, coverHeight);
    coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cover];
    coverView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    coverView.backgroundColor = coverColor;`

Comment: I solved it with a very slight modification of your answer, overriding setCoverColor did the trick. Thanks!